# Need help to group the available order details table to arrive at the distribution of count(order_line_item) , Qty and count(Qty)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, sequelpro

I have a order table with the following information

Order ID, Product ID, Quantity ordered

```
OID PID Qty
1   10  1
1   20  2
2   10  2
2   40  4
3   50  1
3   20  3
4   30  1
4   90  2
4   90  5
5   10  2
5   20  2
5   70  5
5   60  1
6   80  2
```

If I run the following query

```
select `Qty`, count(`Qty`) 
from `table`
group by `Qty`
```

I get the distribution of quantities in the table, which is

```
Qty count(`Qty`)
1   4
2   6 
3   1
4   1
5   2
```

I want to find the distribution of quantity at order_line_item level too

That is how many orders which have one line item, had items with 1 quantity, 2 quantity and so one, something like

```
Count(Order_line_item)    Qty        Count(Qty)
1                         2          1
2                         1          2
2                         2          2
2                         3          1
2                         4          1
3                         1          1
3                         2          1
3                         5          1
4                         1          1
4                         2          2
4                         5          1
```

What modification should i make in the above query to achieve this

Comment: Your sample data does not seem to agree with the description.

Comment: I have updated the description now, kindly suggest the modification to be made to arrive at the sample output table

Comment: The column names still don't line up properly.  Please fix.

Comment: Sure, thank you for the edit suggestion, I have updated the column name in description and the output table @TimBiegeleisen Kindly let me know if any further input is required from my end to get help with this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT  count_order_line_items, `Qty`, count(*)
FROM (
   SELECT count(*) over (partition by `OID`) as count_order_line_items,
         `Qty`
   FROM Table1
) x
GROUP BY count_order_line_items, `Qty`
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07dfb27a7d434eca1f0b9641aadd53c8

If your mysql version is less than 8 then try this one

```
SELECT count_order_line_items, `Qty`, count(*)
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (
   SELECT `OID`, count(*) as count_order_line_items
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY `OID`
) t2 ON t1.`OID` = t2.`OID`
GROUP BY count_order_line_items, `Qty`
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28c291a4693f31029a103f5c41a97d77

Comment: Thank you for your answer @krokodilko  , But when i run this for my table, I am getting the error --------- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by `OID`) as count_order_line_items,
         `Qty`
   F' at line 3

                ------------    what might be causing this since it is working in fiddle

Comment: @sakura01 Your version of mysql is pre 8.0

Comment: ok, I wan't aware about that, Thank you, what can be done in such a case @Strawberry

Comment: I've added a new query for versions less than 8 to my answer

Comment: Thank you @krokodilko this works perfectly for me! :) god bless you !